# Is it possible to programmatically lock the screen in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, lockscreen

I am building an app that will be in kiosk mode and must be over the lock screen its is possible using:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

However, I now need to programmatically lock the screen when the app is starting, looking at [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html) link, I see it needs administrator privileges that are a bit more complicated on the lollipop version, has anyone managed that?

Answer (score 0):

For your need, you can use the [Screen Pinning](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6118421?hl=en). It's a new functionnality added in Android 5 to limit the application a task.

Programmatically, you can use [Activity.startLockTask()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startLockTask()) and [Activity.stopLockTask()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#stopLockTask()) to pin/unpin the application.

Some things to know :

- If your application is not an Admin app, a popup will appear and you'll have to manually confirm the pinning mode.
- No notifications will be shown in this mode.
- The Home and Recent Apps buttons will have no effects.
- you can unpin the application with no confirmation, and if you have set a Keyguard screen, you'll need to unlock it to go back to your Home application.

Comment: Screen pininig is not locked enough for me, its easy to exit it and disrupt the app, also it needs to support 4.0 as well, thank you anyway